# Can two physical vectors form a physical cross product if they are physically separated?

Tags: vectors

I would say that they can't create a cross product.  If they can create a cross product, which seems to be the case from the comments below and answer, then is that cross product consider local or non-local?  But it seems like to me that such a cross product is just a mathematical artifact and can't be a real physical vector **x** x **y** = **z**, that we could measure.  Or can it be measured?  If so, how?

Comment: Can you provide an example? What do you mean by "physically separated"?

Comment: Say that they are two feet apart from each other.

Comment: What is a physical vector in this context? Could you give an example of a cross-product with physical vectors?

Comment: Two angular momentum vectors.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't think of vectors, but physical quantities. Angular momenta will not be able to "interact" if the objects connected to those quantities are separated from each other.

Comment: Would they have to interact to form a cross product?  I'm trying to solve a dispute.

Comment: I would say no, unless you carry one over to the other. This may interest you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport

Comment: In Euclidean space it doesn’t matter where a vector “lives”. We construct cross products of “separated” vectors all the time. For example, when we construct the angular momentum $\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{p}$, $\mathbf{r}$ lives at the origin (in the sense that it points from there to the moving particle) while $\mathbf{p}$ lives at the particle (in the sense that it points from the particle along its direction of motion). When we write a vector, it has three components. They tell us its magnitude and its direction, but not where it lives, because that doesn’t matter in flat space.

Comment: @G. Smith. Not exactly what I had in mind but maybe good enough.  r and p are parts of the same system.  What about two vectors not part of the same system?

Comment: If you add, subtract, or take the scalar or cross product of two vectors in two separate systems in Euclidean space, that’s fine, except that you are then no longer treating them as two separate systems. For example, it is fine to add the momentum vector of system A to the momentum vector of system B and say that that is the momentum vector of the combined system.

Comment: Thanks. Allow me to ask another question.  Say we have **x** and **y** as two angular momentum vectors of the same system but separated by 10 meters with their origins on the same axis.  Is the cross product **x** x **y** considered local or non-local?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, a cross product of two vectors that are "attached" to two spatially separated points would create a non-covariant object. This is because under a general curvilinear transform the components of each of the two vectors transforms with the Jacobian matrix of the transformation evaluated at the respective point. The fact that the cross product is not covariant means that it cannot appear, for instance, as proportional to a force acting on a physical particle. So it is very unlikely that a cross-product of two vectors will be useful for anything.

However, there are certain special cases where spatially separated vectors can "interact". In particular, one often adds vectors such as momentum vectors to define "total vectors". In undergraduate courses this is rarely commented upon, but the procedure of creating such total vectors is well defined only in Cartesian coordinates, and the "total vectors" certainly do not behave as vectors with respect to general curvilinear coordinates.

Then again, certain physical problems have a clear *separation of scales*. In that case we can have, for instance, a body whose physical extent is much smaller than any variability length of an outside problem. We then add the momenta of the components of the small body and replace it mathematically with a massive point particle with the total momentum of the body. We then state covariance of this total momentum with respect to general curvilinear transformations. This will actually be very accurate as long as the "curving scale" of the coordinates stays much larger than the size of the body (which it should, since any coordinate system adapted to the "outside problem" will be like that). This is actually the starting point of any undergraduate classical mechanics course!

Comment: Is that non-covariant object something that is physically real or is it just a math artifact.

Comment: @FredDiether Unless otherwise specified, it cannot appear in a typical physical law. So it is likely not physical. Physicists do not say that something is physical based on mathematics, they say it based on whether it works to describe or predict something real.